# Google Form Document Automation

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have been receiving 2 main issues back upon a google form submission- the first being that the e.values I have set up cannot be read and the second that the Doclist is not defined. I have already set the triggers for the e.values and tried using e.namedvalues as well. I would like to eliminate the second issue by sending a doc and not a pdf to the form submitter, however it is most important that I get the first issue addressed first.

I am using framework that I have modified to fit my own documents, so that may be where I am encountering issues.

```js
// G. Hopper
// Subcontract Generator
// Get template from Google00 Docs and name it
var docTemplate = "16bdl2myh7f0ywlxmf3iimq4Nz6-j8VTs7hkMbshRjp0"; 
var docName = "Subcontract";

// When Form Gets submitted
function onFormSubmit(e) {
//Get information from form and set as variables
var sub_name = e.namedValues["Subcontractor Name"].toString();
var sub_address = e.namedValues["Subcontractor address"].toString();
var proj_name = e.namedValues["Project Name"].toString();
var own_name = e.namedValues["Owner Name"].toString();
var own_address = e.namedValues["Owner Address"].toString();
var designer = e.namedValues["Design Firm"].toString();
var design_address = e.namedValues["Design Firm Address"].toString();
var proj_address = e.namedValues["Project Address"].toString();
var scope = e.namedValues["Scope of work"].toString();
var date_bid = e.namedValues["Date on bid"].toString();
var sub_value = e.namedValues["Subcontract Value"].toString();
var date_pay = e.namedValues["Date of the month pay applications are due"].toString();
var email = e.namedValues["Your email address"].toString();
var day = e.namedValues["Day"].toString();
var month_year = e.namedValues["Month and Year"].toString();

// Get document template, copy it as a new temp doc, and save the Doc’s id
var copyId = DocsList.getFileById(docTemplate)
.makeCopy('Subcontract for '+sub_name)
.getId();
// Open the temporary document
var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);
// Get the document’s body section
var copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection();

// Replace place holder keys,in our google doc template
copyBody.replaceText('keySubName', sub_name);
copyBody.replaceText('keySubAddress', sub_address);
copyBody.replaceText('keyProject', proj_name);
copyBody.replaceText('keyOwner', own_name);
copyBody.replaceText('keyOwnAddress', own_address);
copyBody.replaceText('keyDesigner',designer);
copyBody.replaceText('keyDesignAddress', design_address);
copyBody.replaceText('keyProjAdd', proj_address);
copyBody.replaceText('keyScope', scope);
copyBody.replaceText('keyBidDate', date_bid);
copyBody.replaceText('KeySubValue', sub_value);
copyBody.replaceText('keyPayApp', date_pay);
copyBody.replaceText('keyDay', day);
copyBody.replaceText('keyMonthDay', month_year);

// Save and close the temporary document
copyDoc.saveAndClose();

// Convert temporary document to PDF
var pdf = DocsList.getFileById(copyId).getAs("application/pdf");

// Attach PDF and send the email
var subject = 'Subcontract'
var body = "Here is your subcontract for " + sub_name + "";
MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {htmlBody: body, attachments: pdf});

// Delete temp file
DocsList.getFileById(copyId).setTrashed(true);
}
```

Comment: Is the "On Form Submit" trigger in the Form, or in the Spreadsheet?

Comment: The "On Form Submit" trigger is set up on the form. I tried to set it up as such on the spreadsheet as well, but no luck with that either.